# Custom links in Wordpress navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress site utilizing Bootstrap 3 framework for the navigation. I have the Wordpress enabled navigation contain all my links.

HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right"> 
      <?php /* Primary navigation */
             wp_nav_menu( array(
             'menu' => 'top_menu',
             'depth' => 2,
             'container' => false,
             'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
              //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
             'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
          );
      ?>
```

I want to change the css on one specific button in the navigation. I think this has to be done through the admin side. Possibly through the Title Attribute' tab, not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Menus page in the admin area, at the top right of the screen click "Screen Options" and check the box called "CSS Classes".

You can now go to your menu item and give it a class, which you can now target using CSS.